# Switchpoint Analysis with MCMC Sampling

Tags: time-series, probability, bayesian, pymc3, mcmc

I'm currently trying to reproduce the results of the baysian switchpoint analysis covered in the BMH book. ([Link to Github](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter1_Introduction/Ch1_Introduction_PyMC3.ipynb)) However i'm using a different dataset. I finally got some results but unfortunately I cannot interpret them correctly.

Consider for example the following time series:

[image]

I apply the following code and model the potential changepoint using a discrete uniform distribution and two poisson distributions for the "before" and "after":

```
  lambda_before = pm.Exponential("lambda1", alpha)
  lambda_after = pm.Exponential("lambda2", alpha)

  tau = pm.DiscreteUniform("tau", lower=0, upper=len(weekly))

  idx = np.arange(0, len(weekly)) 
  lambda_ = pm.math.switch(tau > idx, lambda_before, lambda_after)

  observations = pm.Poisson("obs", lambda_, observed=weekly.values)
```

I execute MCMC Sampling and the resulting traceplot looks the following:

[image]

What i understand is that i found a potential switch point which makes sense to me. However there seem to be two different distributions for lambda 1 and lambda 2 which strongly overlap. Is that somehow related to MCMC telling me "Sequential sampling (2 chains in 1 job)" while sampling?

I also saw several cases in which the two distributions (red and blue line) do not overlap at all. In this example, two potential switch points were identified. Now is seems that each "chain" is now sampling data for another switch point. How can this be interpreted?

[image]

Another thing which I think is very confusing is that PyMc seems to mix the values of both "chains" into one result array. This makes it difficult to bring the distributions together with the different tau-values. Is there a trick to do this?

Thanks for helping me out in advance.